# how to install complete tailwind-css properties in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install Tailwind CSS v2.0 into a clean Laravel install, but it is not installing complete css properties like .p-2 and other properties i am following official installation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel but still it is not

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
         require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
      "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

\resources\css\app.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Show us your webpack.mix.js and your `resources/css/app.css`. Your are saying not all properties, but some classes work? witch one?

Comment: i am added it in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently Tailwindcss update their framework(v3.0.7) in which css file is download in purgecss(https://purgecss.com/), thats why you cant download all the classes and properties of tailwindcss.

For that what you can do is download downgraded version of tailwindcss you can download it in your custom folder not even in Laravel.

1. first, run `laravel new your_project_name` in your terminal,
2. run `npm install` or `npm i` on your terminal
3. run `cd/your_project_name` in your terminal
4. run `npm install -D tailwindcss@^1.9.2` in your terminal
5. then go to your project folder and open it on vs code or any code editor
6. add below code in you

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')

```
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [

    require('tailwindcss'),

]);
```

7. add below code in `resources\css\app.css`

   `@tailwind base;`

   `@tailwind components;`

   `@tailwind utilities;`
8. last run `npm run dev` in your cmd

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you're not running `npm run prod` as this purges your css files and removes unused styles.

Run `npm run dev` and see if that helps.

Comment: no it is didn't work